# How to resolve unexpected end of input in file picker moodle

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

Hi Iam using moodle cms to develop my e-learning website everything OK except one problem when i trying to search any youtube video the first image error shown in mozila  firefox second in google crome. [image: mozila file]

[image: cro]

in browse repository enter search keyword when i click ok then this error appear anyone plese help how to resolve.you can find this option in add an activity then page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I am facing same problem,use new youtube plugin for repository list and setup with youtube api key.this will solve your problem chill.